# Is this code for a gift card correct? (Code to print for a gift card)

Tags: javascript, syntax

I'm a python coder, but my brother writes Javascript. For his birthday I want to print a card like this (with the same code):

[image]

Is this code accurate?

```
<script>
var u = 0, age > 1;

while (true){
    if (u == age){
        alert('Happy Birthday!');
        break:
    }
    else { u += 1;}
}
</script>
```

I'm sorry if this is not in the right place to post this question.

Comment: Open your browser's console and try it out! Or e.g. https://repl.it/languages/javascript

Comment: Missing indentation.

Comment: I don't think `var age > 1` would work in Python either.

Comment: There's gotta be a better condition to use than `while(true)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code that you need to attach. If you'd like to have in a separate js file, there is no need for a script block. In contrast, you would have to have a script block (  .... ) if you want to have it in the same page.

Also check the following and this: https://jsfiddle.net/mw4yLwkm/

```js
var u=0, age = 1;

while (1) {
  if (u==true) {
    alert('Happy Birthday');
    break;
  }
  else
    u++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!, sorry for my intrusion on the Javascript world!